# Get the jqueryString from the json files

Tags: jquery, json

I want to return the data from the $.ajax but i can't.. .

```
 function call() {    
    var str = null;
     $.ajax({ url: '/jsonFiles/Products.json',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) { alert(data); str = data; },
                    error: function () { alert("error"); }
                });
    return str; }
```

I get no result.. .  alert(data) can work  then it return the str it failed..  pls 
i want the function that return the JsonString.

Comment: where are you returning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call is made asynchronus witch means that the function will return before the $.ajax call is finished.

It's not recommended but i think you can get around it passing async: false as parameter, eg.

```
$.ajax({ url: '/jsonFiles/Products.json',
                datatype: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) { alert(data); str = data; },
                error: function () { alert("error"); }
            });
```

better yet solution make an other function to call with str when $.ajax is finished

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting that this is asynchronous. Your function `call` returns before the `$.ajax` call finishes, or has any return value. You can't return what `str` is set to in the `success` function because it'll always be executed after the call to `call` finishes. Whatever you need to do with `str`, either do it in the `success` function itself, or save it somewhere in closure/global scope, so that some other function can work with it, elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a synchronous call as suggested by Philip G.

You could also work with callbacks (preferred solution):

```
function call(callback) {    
    $.ajax({ url: '/jsonFiles/Products.json',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: callback,
                error: function () { alert("error"); }
           });
}

// call call with a callback function (anonymous in this example)
call(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```